# Floquet theory in abstract dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, functional-equations, stability-theory

I'm working on a system of functional equations

$$\begin{align}
Q'(t) &=-(\delta(t)+\beta(Q(t))Q(t)+2(1-K(t))e^{-\gamma(t)\tau}u(t-\tau) \tag{Eq1}\\[8pt]
u(t) &=\beta(Q(t))Q(t)+2K(t)e^{-\gamma(t)\tau}u(t-\tau)\tag{Eq2}
\end{align}$$

where $K$,$\gamma$ and $\delta$ are $T$-periodic functions. It cannot be put as an abstract ODE (at least I don't know how), but is still a dynamical system. I've proven the existence of a $T$ periodic solution using topological methods. Now I want to study the stability of such solution. Do you know if there is some kind of Floquet theory for abstract dynamical systems?
Thanks!

Comment: You really need to say a bit what the functions are. Also, should it be $u'(t)$ in the second line? If not it will be very difficult to say something meaningful.

Comment: Q, u, K, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are scalar functions. And no, the second equation is not differential. That is why I said it was not an ODE in a Banach space, as far as I can see.

Comment: Even though, for each $Q_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi \in C=C([-\tau, 0])$, there is a unique solution and it can be seen as a dynamical system in $\mathbb{R} \times C$

Comment: In that case, I really think that Floquet is out of the question. Even considering $u(t)$ and $\beta(Q(t))$ as known a priori, I don't see how to use multipliers. Better Lyapunov functions?